# How to migrate datas from version 14 to 15 in odoo

Tags: odoo-15

I'm having database with data in version 14 and also having new database without demo data in version 15. I need to transfer data from v 14 to v 15.

Any help is appreciable!

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options to do that,

1. As you can use OCA's library for that https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade/tree/15.0
2. Make your own script with https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/misc/api/odoo.html#logging-in

Comment: Could you please help me to know how to use this and run it in terminal @saumil

Comment: For the xmlrpc you can go though with the given doc and make a python script which you can run in terminal by executing "python your_script.py"

Answer (score 0):

To migrate an odoo database from version 13 to higher versions
1- download OpenUpgrade
2- Clone odoo (available on github)
In the odoo folder there is an odoo-bin file that will allow you to start the migration
For details on the migration refer to the link below https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-the-odoo-15-database-using-openupgrade
To migrate from version A to version B, you must go to the branch identical to version B in the Odoo and OpenUpgrade folders
THANKS.